# How do "invisible" function parameters in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell

An example of what I am talking about is [`takeWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile)

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Example usage

```
takeWhile (< 3) [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4] == [1,2]
```

From what I can tell `(< 3)` becomes `(a < 3)` where a is the current item in the list being checked.

How is this done in Haskell and how would I be able to move where `a` goes so I could do something like

```
takeWhile ((length a) < 4) ["aaa", "aaaaa"]
```

Comment: If you're looking for Google juice: That syntax, where you leave out one operand of a symbolic infix operator, is called a _section_. `(< 3)` means `(\x -> x < 3)` and `("abc" ++)` means `(\x -> "abc" ++ x)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(< 3)` is called a "section" and works only with infix operators. It's a syntactic sugar to write abbreviated functions. `(< 3)` is equivalent to `\x -> x < 3` and `(3 <)` is equivalent to `\x -> 3 < x`.

Thus, `(< 3)` is a function of one argument that returns a `Bool`. Which is exactly what `takeWhile` expects.

With `length`, you have to write a function in full:

```
takeWhile (\x -> length x < 4) ["aaa", "aaaaa"]
```

or define your own function you can curry:

```
shorterThan n x = length x < n

takeWhile (shorterThan 4) ["aaa", "aaaaa"]
```

If you are feeling adventurous, you can write

```
takeWhile ((< 4) . length) ["aaa", "aaaaa"]
```

or perhaps in a more readable fashion

```
(??) = flip (.)

takeWhile (length ?? (< 4)) ["aaa", "aaaaa"]
```

Comment: Haskell has trained me so much to read function composition right to left, that the `??` version is less readable to me.

Comment: @4castle It's a composition but don't read it as such. Think of ?? as a placeholder for a variable. "Length of something is less than four".

Answer (score 3):

There go nowhere, you have to remember that every function in Haskell is currified, so, think in the `(+)` function, you can do the next, think in the type first:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

now I can do my custom plusOne, plusTwo, etc, so fast thanks to the curryfication, because

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

has "implicit paranthesis" and really looks like:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> (a -> a)
```

meaning give me a number a give you a function back, so:

```
plusOne :: Num a => a -> a
plusOne = (+1)

plusTwo :: Num a => a -> a
plusTwo = (+2)
```

Can you see? you transform the `(+)` in a new function by giving to it just one of the two parameters, same happens with `<` and  `>`  functions, you can create the function `greaterThanTen` like this:

```
greaterThanTen :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
greaterThanTen = (>10)
```

So in your example of `takeWhile (< 3)` your `(< 3)` is the function "less than 3", and if you "read" all the function would be "take while n is less than 3"

you can play around with it in the console by asking the types with `:t` command

```
  :t (< 3)
(< 3) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Bool
```

Comment: Note however that `(>10) 4` is quite different from `(>) 10 4`. While currying / partial application lets one fix the first argument, the section syntax allows for both `(10<)` and `(10<)` -- this is not simply currying at work, it receives special parsing and handling from the compiler.

Comment: @chi thank you so much, with such an expert like you I learn something new every day :), like... yesterday! If my memory doesn't fails, thanks so much for the comment and the time

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `takeWhile` is a predicate; this is your unary function `(< 3)`, which is true, when the argument has numeric semantics and is less than `3`. This option is applied to each list member, making up a new list and terminating, when the predicate is not true the first time. The elements, which have passed, make up the result list.

Your example is almost correct, you must only convert it into predicate form, i.e. create an unary function, which is true, when the parameter (a string) has a length less than 4. This can for example done by

```
(\a -> (length a) < 4)
```

then

```
takeWhile (\a -> (length a) < 4) ["aaa", "aaaaa"]
```

should     do what you expect.